# Suppose $M$ be a finitely generated $R$ module such that $M \oplus R \cong R$ then is it true that $M=0$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

> Suppose $M$ be a module over a commutative ring $R$ such that $M \oplus R \cong R$. Then is it true that $M=0$ ?

I think the claim is true but i don't see a proof for this. Please help.

Comment: Hint. $\wedge^2R=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $M \oplus R \cong R$, $R$ has an ideal $I$ (the image of $M$ w.r.t this isomorphism) with $R/I \cong R$. In particular $0 = \operatorname{Ann} R = \operatorname{Ann} R/I=I \cong M$.

Comment: Nice! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Moos: Does  $M \oplus R^n \cong R^n$ also implies $N=0$ ?

Comment: Yes, but we need another proof in this case. Note that we can reduce to the local case. Then the assumption yields that $M$ is projective, hence free. For a free module, this is well known.

Answer (score 2):

If we have $M \oplus R \cong R$, then $M \oplus R$ is cyclic. Let $(m,r) \in M \oplus R$ be a generator. Then $r \in R$ is a unit and we can w.l.o.g. assume $r = 1$. Assume we have $m \neq n \in M$. Then the pair $(n,1)$ is not a multiple of $(m,1)$ (as $1$ is only fixed by $1$ under multiplication), hence a contradiction. Thus $M$ contains but a single element.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice answers. Here is another one for the sake of completeness.

Since $M\oplus R \cong R$ there is split exact sequence

[image]

with $p\circ i = id$. But since $\text{Hom}(R,R)=R$ and $R$ is commutative it follows $i\circ p = id$. Hence $p$ is an isomorphism and $M = \text{ker } p = 0$.